# Install Ubuntu Server on AMD Chipset RAID array

Tags: server, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a new system. The system has a Gigabyte TRX40 Aorus Master motherboard and I have used Raidxpert2 to create a RAID1 array across two NVMe drives.

When I run the Ubuntu Server 20.04 setup process, it doesn't seem to see the array. Instead, it gives me the option of installing to either of the underlying drives.

I've done some Googling and found [this driver](https://github.com/thopiekar/rcraid-dkms) for AMD chipset raid, but it seems that in order to install it you need Linux to already be installed. I think this means it can't be used for the boot partition.

I also found [this guide](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/raid-b350-ubuntu-18-04-2/td-p/267411) but this relies on the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option which is not available for Ubuntu Server.

How can I install Ubuntu Server so that it boots from an array?

Answer (score -1):

You are better off using software raid in most cases. The CPU can handle it fine and its much less complicated and more widely compatible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can't boot from software RAID. My goal here was to use RAID for the boot drive.